# Create Virtual Directory IIS7 to be use in GetFolder in Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7.5, virtual-directory, filesystemobject

I am trying to create a virtual directory at my IIS7 and then use the virtual directory in the following code

```
sPath = "\CMapped\database\attendanceData\"

sDir = Server.MapPath(".") & sPath
    
response.write sDir

Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set obj_FolderBase = fso.GetFolder(sDir)
    
response.end
```

But I got the following error:

[image: error]

## What I have done is as follow:

1. I created the virtual directory and set the path to C:\ Drive. My localhost is at D:\ drive. I have also set Connect as and entered my log in and password. I am the administrator of the PC. Everything authorized.

   [image: Authorized]
2. Then I go to C: and set it as a shared folder

   [image: Shared]
3. I went back to IIS and click on the virtual directory -> Managed Virtual Directory -> Browse. I successfully connect to the directory

[image: Success]

## Now when I try the code, everything failed. The GetFolder function doesn't seems to recognize the path. The web server is at D: and the file server is at C: Please help.

```
sPath = "\CMapped\database\attendanceData\"

sDir = Server.MapPath(".") & sPath
    
response.write sDir

Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set obj_FolderBase = fso.GetFolder(sDir)
    
response.end
```

The directory structure

[image: DirectoryStructure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying would work in an `href` or `src` attribute, or with

`<!--#include virtual="\CMapped\database\attendanceData\yourfile.asp"-->`.

With  `server.mappath` though I think you need to use the physical directory structure on the machine.  As your virtual directory is on a different drive I suggest you go with

```
sDir = "C:\full_physical_path_to\database\attendanceData\"
```

Comment: sorry I don't quite understand what you trying to say. Is there a way to pass the right path to `fso.GetFolder(sDir)`?