# Can't connect to mapped drive in GetFolder for FileSystemObject ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic, filesystems, mapped-drive

I am trying to connect to `R:\database\attendanceData\` a mapped drive to be used in the following code

```vb
sDir = "R:\database\attendanceData\"

Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set obj_FolderBase = fso.GetFolder(sDir)

if obj_FolderBase.Files.Count = 0 then '=== Check if Attendance record data is in
    response.write " No Attendance Data Found!"
    response.End 
end if

response.write "IT is working"
response.End
```

The file structure

[image: Structure]

But I get the following error

[image: Error]

However if I move my files to `C:` drive, everything is working.

But it needs to be in a shared drive. Do I need to set some permission at `R:` or am I missing something, please help.

Comment: can you read the root `R:\` folders?

Comment: you're best bet is to map the location in IIS as a virtual folder, then you should have no issues reading from it

Comment: @Ricardo Pontual yes I can read the root of R

Comment: @Josh Montgomery, I tried your method but couldn't get the path to work. Any pointers please

Comment: @JoshMontgomery Can you please look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50500456/create-virtual-directory-iis7-to-be-use-in-getfolder-in-server-createobjectscr

Comment: if you are able to access the folder/files at root of `R:` you should be able to read the child folders. The path don't have any special characters, so that is not the issue, is there any special permission set to the "attendanceData" folder that is different from the root?

Comment: Even though you can see R:, the user that IIS is running under may not be able to see it.   As Josh recommended, map it as a IIS virtual folder.

Comment: Once I've set the virtual directory, how would I reference it in `GetFolder`?